# Usage: waterhed.py [-h] -i IMAGE waterhed.py: error: unrecognized arguments

Tags: python, image-processing, command-line-arguments

```
   ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,

         help="path to input image")

   args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

when I use

```
python image.py -- image C/:.... path of image .....
```

I get the error message:

```
waterhed.py [-h] -i IMAGE waterhed.py: error: unrecognized arguments
```

Why did I get this error and how would I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between the double dash (`-- image` -> `--image`), and also wrap paths with spaces in quotes:

```
python waterhed.py --image "C:/path of image.jpg"
```